# How do I float div to the next one

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I am trying to put a div next to each other. I have tried to use `float: left` etc, also I am using bootstrap however I have tried the column setting but it does not work,

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="Mainbody2">
        <div class="ref1">
            <h2>About</h2>
            <p>Text GOES HERE</p>
            <h2>Statement!</h2>
            <p>STATMENT GOES HERE</p><br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <h2>Number1</h2>
            <ul>
                <li>link1</li>
                <li>link1</li>
                <li>link1</li>
                <li style="list-style: none"><br /></li>
                <li>link1</li>
                <li>link1</li>
                <li>link1</li>
                <li style="list-style: none"><br /></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="ref2">
            <h2>Description</h2>
            <ul>
                <li>link2</li>
                <li>link2</li>
                <li>link2</li>
                <li style="list-style: none">
                    <br />
                    <h2>Libraries</h2>
                </li>
                <li>link2</li>
                <li>link2</li>
                <li>link2</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Link to [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/14576/)

Just to make it clear i am trying to get Description next to Number 1 and then Libraries next to description

Thanks again for the help

Comment: the fiddle that you reffered to doesnt have anything that you posted in your question..

Comment: is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/14580/) what you want?

Comment: ah yes but i need them to be inline with each other just under the statment

Comment: like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/14581/) ?

Comment: ah like this http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/14582/ but u see there is no space, i need to try andadd some space somehow

Comment: please see my asnwer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/14583/)

I've changed your HTML a bit as below

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="Mainbody2">
    <div class="ref1">
      <div class="left">
        <h2>About</h2>
        <p>Text GOES HERE </p>
        <h2>Statement!</h2>
        <p>
          STATMENT GOES HERE
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="right">
        <h2>Description</h2>
        <li> link2</li>
        <li> link2</li>
        <li> link2</li>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ref2">
      <div class="left">
        <h2>Number1</h2>
        <li> link1</li>
        <li> link1</li>
        <li> link1</li>
        <br>
        <li> link1</li>
        <li> link1</li>
        <li> link1</li>
      </div>
      <div class="right">
        <h2>Libraries</h2>
        <li> link2</li>
        <li> link2</li>
        <li> link2</li>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

also, added the below CSS

```
.left,
.right,.ref1,.ref2 {
  float: left;
}
.ref1,.ref2{

  padding:10px;
  width:100%;
}
.left,.right{
  width:50%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

add md and sm to you div   `<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2">`

```
    <div class="container">
                    <div class="Mainbody2">
                 <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs2">            
                   <h2>About</h2>
               <p>Text GOES HERE  </p>
                  <h2>Statement!</h2>
              <p>
                 STATMENT GOES HERE
              </p>
              <br />  <br />  <br />
             <h2>Number1</h2>
               <li> link1</li>
               <li> link1</li>
               <li> link1</li>
              <br />
               <li> link1</li>
             <li> link1</li>
           <li> link1</li>
             <br />
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs2">
             <h2>Description</h2>
           <li> link2</li>
           <li> link2</li>
           <li> link2</li>
           <br />
             <h2>Libraries</h2>
           <li> link2</li>
           <li> link2</li>
            <li> link2</li>
                 </div>
        </div>  
  </div>
```

see js fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vrupp3wr/

set the proper col lenght  for your need

Comment: Hi, yes i was trying to add this to my example, with the row etc but i am not sure why its not working, i could be making a silly mistake but i dont think so

Comment: Ah ye sorry i uploaded the wrong fiddle, the link has been put in again , sorry again my fault

Comment: I have update the answer .. the same problem .. you need col-md col-sm col-xs

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">column 1</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">column 2</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">column 3</div>
</div>
```

With Bootstrap you have to designate one div as a row and the nested divs can be columns.

Answer (score 0):

```
this works for me
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div class="panel">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Legend</legend>
                <div class="radio">
                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" value="option1" checked>
                        Option one
                    </label>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div class="panel">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Legend</legend>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputEmail">
                        Email address</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail" placeholder="Enter email">
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah ye sorry i uploaded the wrong fiddle, the link has been put in again , sorry again my fault